how to write a mixed model with random effects
I'm trying to carcaterize rootstocks according to their wood weight.
I wrote a mixed model and I would like to know if it is correct and what to do since the conditions of application of this model aren't verified.
The fixed effects are the density, the vine age, the year of measurement and the region. The random effects are the rootstocks and the varieties.
I wrote the following model :
modele <- lmer(valeur_corr ~ region_non_vide / annee_mesures + classe_densite_plant + classe_age_vigne + (1|portegreffe/greffon), data = data_clean)
R sent me the following message error : fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 97 columns / coefficients
summary(modele)
enter image description here
And I checked the conditions of application of the model with plotresid(modele)
enter image description here
The homoscedasticity and normality aren't checked. And the histogram of values shows the values don't follow either a poisson model or a normal modele or a binomial model.
enter image description here
So do I have to use a nlme since the conditions of application aren't checked ? If yes how ?
Thank you very much for your help.
Sincerely.
